# How to disable package deduplication for a single dependency?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

My Node/Electron project has a dependency graph sort of like this:

- My Project

  - `aaa@^4.0`

    - `bbb@^5.6`

      - `ccc@^1.0.0`
  - `ddd@^0.8`

    - `ccc@^1.0.1`
    - `eee@^4.4`
  - `eee@^4.3`

`npm install` resolves this to the following `node_modules`:

- `aaa@4.0`
- `bbb@5.6`
- `ccc@1.0.1`
- `ddd@0.8`
- `eee@4.4`

It figures that `ccc@1.0.0` and `1.0.1` are compatible and deduplicates them, as it should. However, runtime errors indicate that they are, in fact, not compatible at all. That is, `bbb@5.6` does not work with `ccc@1.0.1` and requires `1.0.0`.

Now, I could use `--legacy-bundling` so both versions would be installed, as nested modules in those that depend on them, but I don't want to do that for all dependencies. Specifically, there must be only one copy of `eee` at runtime.

How can I disable the deduplication for either `aaa` and all its dependencies or just for `bbb`? Preferably in NPM, but I'm willing to switch to Yarn or another tool if needed.

---

Edit: the question originally used `ccc` versions `1.0` and `2.0`, but I was wrong, `npm` did in fact view those as *not* compatible and already installed them the way I wanted. My problem was with Webpack after all. So I've updated the question to the current version, which is still a possible scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that it can be achieved by

- editing `package-lock.json`
- and changing `.["packages"]["node_modules/bbb"]["dependencies"]["bbb"]`
- from `"^1.0.0"`
- to `"1.0.0"`,
- then running `npm ci`.

I have no idea if this is the proper way to do it, but at least running `npm i` doesn't overwrite the change.

Now I'm running into the problem that Webpack doesn't resolve `bbb`'s import to the nested `ccc`, but that's outside of the scope of this question...